# Is there a boto3 funciton to convert authorization_code into authorization_token

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cognito

My project is python and using boto3 lib.

I'm using aws cognito Authorization code grant flow with `return_type=code` instead of `return_type=token` (implicit flow). Once my user is authorized my redirect url is injected with the queryStringParameter `code=4d55a121-8ffc-4058-844b-xxxx`.

outlined [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html)

I need to be able to verify this code. Because of course someone can take the redirect url and make a fake code and paste it into the browser. According to this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) I can exchange the code for a token. This works as expected via a rest client. I get the token and can continue to pass the token as the Authorization header. But what I'm asking is there has to be a boto3 method that takes this code and converts it into a token for me. If i have to use the requests lib I will.

I have tried for days. `get_user` isnt the answer as that requires a token not the code.

For reference on what I'm trying to do heres my repo. The focus is in `def edit()`. I'm currently using requests to achieve the same thing but would like to use the boto library
https://github.com/knittledan/python-lambda-cognito

Answer (score 1):

Nope, believe you should use an https client to exchange the authorization code for tokens with the token endpoint provided:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html